# Is having a Delegate Manager a good design idea?

Tags: android, oop, design-patterns

Many Android apps include a BaseActivity class of their own, which all Activities in the app extend. This is useful because it gives a central place to put functionality that's common across most/all activities. The main drawback of having a BaseActivity is you are then unable to use any of the Activity subclasses (ListActivity, etc.).

One alternative is to have an ActivityDelegate. This gives a central place for functionality while still allowing you to use Activity subclasses. It's also arguably more testable, since it uses composition instead of inheritance.

Both of these solutions potentially lead to a lot of spaghetti code when the BaseActivity/ActivityDelegate gets too large and convoluted. A possible solution to this is to use the delegate pattern, but split the functionality into many different Delegates. This reduces spaghetti code in the Delegates, but then the Activities get more complicated - they're now trying to forward their on* methods to lots of different Delegates instead of just one.

A possible solution to all of these problems is to use a Delegate Manager. The Delegate Manager keeps track of all the smaller Delegates in the app. Activities forward their on* methods to the Delegate Manager, which forwards them on to all of the individual Delegates. This accomplishes all of the following:

- Dedupes code - all common functionality gets placed into one of the Delegates
- Allows use of Activity subclasses
- Simple code in all Activities - all on* methods are forwarded to just one class
- Easily testable - it's simple to mock out everything around the Delegates and the Delegate Manager for unit tests

Has anyone tried using this pattern before? If so, how did it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you're talking about one single DelegateManager object for the entire application. If this is the case, you can use **registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks**, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks%28android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks%29

If you're on < API level 14 you need to take a look at: https://github.com/BoD/android-activitylifecyclecallbacks-compat.

`registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` lets you hook into the activities onXXX lifecycle methods.

**Doing this certainly has all the benefits you described:**

- decoupling being usable only when you actually need to repeat behavior which is kinda seldom for controller+view logic tied in together the way Activity works.
- Removing inheritance is nice if you have activities you might reuse - but I've never had to do it before. But I guess a good use-case would be your home-cooked activity for handling settings or something like it that needs app-wide L&F & behavior.

**On the top of my head I can think of these downsides:**

- Using listeners all over the place can blur path of the application activity/call hierarchy and can make the code hard to understand. This holds true for all listener/dispatcher type of programming. It's a powerful tool, but handle it with care.
- It can introduce a lot of (as you mention) boilerplate/spaghetti code if all you do is pass on to lifecycle listeners/delegates.
- it is your responsibility to de-register yourself from the Application with `Application.unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks`. I don't think there's a good way around it,

Personally I haven't used this design-pattern much for lifecycles, **but it might be worthwhile for some use-cases**. For example:

- ApplicationLifecycleLogger: Every time you create/resume/pause... an activity, you logcat or something else making debugging lifecycles a tad bit easier.
- If for example someone goes into an activity he/she is not allowed to go into due to model state of some sort (e.g. a ringing alarm -> can't go into AlarmEditActivity), you could do finish() there.
- Passing object state across activity boundaries without Parcelable:s and screen rotation changes. Usually this is implemented with a Map in Application or some static field somewhere. You can do this by letting the delegators hold state.

Also, take a look at: [Is there a design pattern to cut down on code duplication when subclassing Activities in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587186/is-there-a-design-pattern-to-cut-down-on-code-duplication-when-subclassing-activ?rq=1)

I hope this was helpful =)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One of my main needs for this type of pattern is to display a "Network Error" screen whenever the network fails to load. I do network stuff in both activities and fragments, so I need the same screen to display for both. With a delegate, I've been able to put all the code for displaying a network error in one place; if I were to use inheritance, I'd need a BaseActivity and then I suppose a BaseFragment as well, both containing very similar code. Have you run across this use case? If so, have you been able to handle it with inheritance without duping code?

Comment: I apologize for this late reply. "Network Error" seems like a legitimate use case - it is somewhat similar to "ApplicationLifecycleLogger" in that its use is motivated in most activities in a network based app. Personally, I haven't written such an app so I haven't encountered it yet.